# Show More/Show Less Button To Control Table Individual Table Hight

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

I hope that all is well. I am trying to use a button to extend a specific row. Right now, I can press the "show more/show less button," and it extends all the rows. However, the main goal is to do it for each individual table caption row. The other goal is to show the button if the caption length is more than 250. Below is the code for visual understanding. Please let me know if the questions does not make any sense. Otherwise, any advice will do! Thank you!

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './Home.css'
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Dependencies
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
//Function
import VerificationCheck from "../../Functions/VerificationCheck";


const Home = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const userLoggedIn = VerificationCheck.CheckLogin();
    const loggedInUser = VerificationCheck.CheckUser();
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [posts, setPost] = useState([]);
    const [statusMessage, setStatusMessage] = useState(null);
    const [displayShowMore, setDisplayShowMore] = useState(false);
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!userLoggedIn) {
            navigate('/Login', {
                state: {
                    previousUrl: location.pathname,
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            getAllPost();
        }
    }, [userLoggedIn]);
    
    const getAllPost = () => {
        const url = process.env.REACT_APP_Backend_URL + '/post/get-post-record';

        Axios.post (url)
        .then ((response) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
                if (response.data[i].postsCaption.length > 250) {
                    setDisplayShowMore(true);
                }
            }
            setPost(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStatusMessage("Server Side Error");
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='homeBody'>
                <div className="homeForm">
                    {isLoading ?
                    <>
                        <h1>Loading...</h1>
                    </>
                    :
                    <>
                        {statusMessage ? 
                        <>
                            <h1>{statusMessage}</h1>
                        </>
                        :
                        <>
                            {posts.map(uploadedPost => (
                                <table>
                                    <tbody className="postData" key={uploadedPost.postsID}>
                                        <tr><td><a><h1 className="title">{uploadedPost.postsTitle}</h1></a></td></tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <div className="authorDate">
                                                    <h2 className="author">Author: {uploadedPost.postsAuthor}</h2>
                                                    <h3 className="datetime">{uploadedPost.createdOn}</h3>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr><td className="btn"><button className="btn" onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}>{showMore ? "Show less" : "Show more"}</button></td></tr>
                                        <tr><td><p className="caption">{showMore ? uploadedPost.postsCaption : `${uploadedPost.postsCaption.substring(0, 250)}`}{showMore ? "" : "..."}</p></td></tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            ))}
                        </>
                        }
                    </>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already kind of doing that. Instead of setting the `setDisplayShowMore` state variable, you can construct a new object with that field for each specific post.

```
const getAllPost = () => {
        const url = process.env.REACT_APP_Backend_URL + '/post/get-post-record';

        Axios.post (url)
        .then ((response) => {
            const _data = response.data;
            for (var i = 0; i < _data.length; i++){
                _data[i].displayMore = false;
            }
            setPost(_data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            setStatusMessage("Server Side Error");
            setIsLoading(false);
        });
    }
```

Now you can change this field in each table to determine how many rows to show. One thing to keep in mind is that you can't modify the state directly in place, but rather you have to replace the entire `posts` state variable once you decide to update the table rows.

Edit: Here is more info on what I mean.

This code replaces the displayMore to match what the user clicked. So instead of having the `showMore` state, you can just use this field. This function goes where you would put any other function like the ones you used to fetch the posts.

```
const handleShowMore = (post_id) => {
                
                    const current_state = [...posts];
                  
                  const current_post = current_state.find(p => p.postsID === post_id);
                  
                  if(!current_post) {
                  // couldn't find the post, ID's dont match
                  return;
                  }

                  // replace the current state to the opposite
                  current_post.displayMore = !current_post.displayMore;
                  setPosts(current_state);
                }
```

Now here we are using the displayMore field to determine what button to show and whether to show the ellipses or not.

```
{posts.map(uploadedPost => (
                            <table>
                                <tbody className="postData" key={uploadedPost.postsID}>
                                    <tr><td><a><h1 className="title">{uploadedPost.postsTitle}</h1></a></td></tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div className="authorDate">
                                                <h2 className="author">Author: {uploadedPost.postsAuthor}</h2>
                                                <h3 className="datetime">{uploadedPost.createdOn}</h3>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr><td className="btn"><button className="btn" onClick={() => handleShowMore(uploadedPost.postsID)}>{uploadedPost.displayMore ? "Show less" : "Show more"}</button></td></tr>
                                    <tr><td><p className="caption">{uploadedPost.displayMore ? uploadedPost.postsCaption : `${uploadedPost.postsCaption.substring(0, 250)}`}{uploadedPost.displayMore ? "" : "..."}</p></td></tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        ))}
                    </>
                    }
                </>
                }
```

Sorry the formatting is so off, idk why stackoverflow did it this way.

Comment: So this still does the same thing right now. The goal is to do it individually.

Comment: I'll edit my original post with some more info.

Comment: Now I see what you meant, and this makes more sense now actually! Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: No problem, hope it helps!